# androidX navigation and bottom navi view issue?

Tags: android

```
implementation android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha04
implementation android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha04
```

I use androidX's navigation library and bottom navigation view,before I use alpha03 version,no problem,but today I change to 04 version and androidx support to 1.0.0-rc01,I meet a problem like this:

my bottom navi contains A,B,C,D,E tabs and 5 fragments,when i switch from A to B,and switch to one of C,D,E,enter android back,fragments has replace from C,D or E to A,but bottom tab no changes,still C,D or E

```
navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_nav);
            navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigation, navController);
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my MainActivity‘s onBackPressed function:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    navController.navigateUp();
}
```

I found the old code switch from c to a by click back button,

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigation, navController);
```

this function inner code

```
navController.addOnNavigatedListener(new NavController.OnNavigatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigated(@NonNull NavController controller,
                @NonNull NavDestination destination) {
            Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
            for (int h = 0, size = menu.size(); h < size; h++) {
                MenuItem item = menu.getItem(h);
                if (matchDestination(destination, item.getItemId())) {
                    item.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

not run,I don't know why but copy navController.navigateUp(); from onSupportNavigateUp() to onBackPressed,this inner function run success.